# google-spreadsheet node.js. Copying and pasting cells in the range

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, google-sheets-api

there! I have two ranges of cells **BM4:BM29** and **BN4:BN29**. I need to copy the cell values from the first range and paste into the other range. The cells in the first range have formulas that add up the numbers in the other cells in the table. I need to copy this number and paste into the other range.

I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet/v/4.1.0

To authenticate, I use:

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet');
const { JWT } = require('google-auth-library');
require("dotenv").config();

const serviceAccountAuth = new JWT({
    email: process.env.GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key: process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
    scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    ],
});
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(process.env.SPREADSHEET_TABLE_ID, serviceAccountAuth);

module.exports = { doc };
```

I have tried many different methods but they have not produced any results.

```
await doc.loadInfo();
const sheet = doc.sheetsById[SOME_SHEET_ID];
await sheet.loadCells();

sheet.loadCellsInRange()
sheet.copyPaste()
sheet.getCellByA1()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms4hP.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZdC3.png

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `I have two ranges of cells BM4:BM29 and BN4:BN29. I need to copy the cell values from the first range and paste into the other range. The cells in the first range have formulas that add up the numbers in the other cells in the table. I need to copy this number and paste into the other range.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? And, First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: For example: I have `BK` and `BL` speakers. Some numbers are written in `cells 4 to 29`. There is a column `BM`, which adds up all numbers in `cells 4 to 29` and gets the sum. I need to transfer all the values in column `BM` to column `BN`.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: That's okay, my English can have mistakes in it too because it's pretty low level. I added screenshots from the table with formulas. I need the values from column BM to be copied to column BN

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your following reply,

> I added screenshots from the table with formulas. I need the values from column BM to be copied to column BN

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, the values of column "BM" are copied to column "BN" using the batchUpdate method. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the batchUpdate method in [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet/v/4.1.0). So, I directly request Sheets API using `https` module. The access token and Spreadsheet ID are retrieved from `doc` in your script, respectively. Please modify as follows.

#### From:

```js
await doc.loadInfo();
const sheet = doc.sheetsById[SOME_SHEET_ID];
await sheet.loadCells();

sheet.loadCellsInRange()
sheet.copyPaste()
sheet.getCellByA1()
```

#### To:

Please set your sheet ID.

```js
const https = require("https");

const sheetId = 12345678; // Please set your sheet ID.

const srcStartColumnIndex = 64; // Column "BM"
const dstStartColumnIndex = 65; // Column "BN"

const url = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${doc.spreadsheetId}:batchUpdate`;
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + doc.jwtClient.gtoken.rawToken.access_token,
  },
};
const postData = {
  requests: [
    {
      copyPaste: {
        source: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, startColumnIndex: srcStartColumnIndex, endColumnIndex: srcStartColumnIndex + 1 },
        destination: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, startColumnIndex: dstStartColumnIndex, endColumnIndex: dstStartColumnIndex + 1 },
        pasteType: "PASTE_VALUES",
      },
    },
  ],
};
const req = https.request(url, options, (res) => {
  const chunks = [];
  res
    .on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)))
    .on("end", () => console.log(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()));
});
req.write(JSON.stringify(postData));
req.on("error", (err) => console.log(err));
req.end();
```

- By this modification, when this script is run, the values of column "BM" are copied to column "BN" using the batchUpdate method by one API call. In this case, only values are copied.
- If you want to copy "BM4:BM29" to "BN4:BN29", please modify `source: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, startColumnIndex: srcStartColumnIndex, endColumnIndex: srcStartColumnIndex + 1 },` and `destination: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 0, startColumnIndex: dstStartColumnIndex, endColumnIndex: dstStartColumnIndex + 1 },` as follows.

  - `source: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 3, endRowIndex: 29, startColumnIndex: srcStartColumnIndex, endColumnIndex: srcStartColumnIndex + 1 },`
  - `destination: { sheetId, startRowIndex: 3, endRowIndex: 29, startColumnIndex: dstStartColumnIndex, endColumnIndex: dstStartColumnIndex + 1 },`

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [CopyPasteRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#copypasterequest)